# rails render_to_string of an partial that contain a <script> tag doesn't executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cableready

I am trying to insert html with a render_to_string of a partial that contain a  , the problem is that this script does not run, is there any way to rerun the inserted scripts?

ref. I am using Cable Ready morph to insert the html. I have inspected the DOM and the partial  is inserted correctly in the view, but the script does not execute.

I really appreciate any help, thanks

```
   cable_ready['workflow'].morph(
      selector: '#active_' + ActionView::RecordIdentifier.dom_id(attention_request),
      html: render_to_string(
        partial: "payments/partial",
        locals: {
          professional_quote: professional_quote,
        }
      )
    )
    cable_ready.broadcast
```

partial.html.erb

```
  <%= form_tag payments_mercado_pago_payments_path, method: :post, class: '' do %>
    <script
     src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
     data-preference-id="<%= professional_quote.preference_id %>">
    </script>
  <% end %>
```